# Magento 2 How To Create File Upload Controller in Ui Component Form

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, file-upload

I have created one custom extension that creates one grid using UI component so now, on this create one control file upload type, and using this control I want to upload one PDF file and save it on the var directory.

I am able to upload the image but the PDF file did not upload on the var directory and did not show its control.

Anyone know, how to do this?

Comment: it is require for your pdf file save in var directory. i am said to you save in pub/media directory

Comment: Add here the code whatever you have tried for that.